# Is there a way to combine sound settings on iOS?

Tags: ios, audio, settings

I have discovered that iOS (5) has two sound settings: "Sound effects" and just "sound" with no title. Due to this I often have sound effects muted but not other app sounds, and it's not easy to mute/enable one type of sound and not the other.

Is there any way in iOS 5 to change both sound effects and general sounds using only the volume rocker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer is simply **no**, sound effects and general sound are two different volume levels.

The reasoning seems to be that some apps are focused around sound, so muted sound effects doesn't mean music shouldn't play.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the setting you are after is in

`Settings -> Sounds`  Change with Buttons = On

Comment: I have this option on; it appears to only affect ringers and alerts, not "sound effects" vs "music" which seems to be the distinction.